# COPY INTO snowflake table not loading data even with Force command and also no error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying loading data from s3 bucket to snowflake table & using the copy into command.
This is my command:

```
copy into "BUSINESS_DB"."BI_REPORTING"."MODELING_FEATS_PH_RAW"
from s3://ph-stage-data-model-pipeline-magneto/experiment/modeling_feats.csv credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='XXXXXX')
FILE_FORMAT = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE 
NULL_IF = ('NULL','null','')) ON_ERROR = CONTINUE PURGE=TRUE FORCE=TRUE
;
```

The first time it worked perfectly, when I tried to reload it again it its throwing error:Copy executed with 0 files processed. Could some please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You used **PURGE=TRUE** which would remove your files from the stage. Have you checked the files are still present on the stage?

Try using [LIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) to see if you still have the files on the stage.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the quick response, I am kind of new to all this. Does that mean the csv file would have been removed from S3?

Comment: Yes, and second time there would be nothing to load.

Comment: So if the file is reloaded into S3, and next time when I run the code and put purge = false. then everything would work correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is the expectation, taking into account the first time was loaded successfully.

Comment: yes, it was loaded correctly the first time